# MySQL, optimize and replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I have two MySQL (MariaDB actually) servers, a master and a slave with standard replication.
Two times already in less than a month I've had my slave become unusable.

This is what I experienced:

- Notice a drop in query per second on the slave with my monitoring tool
- Connect to the server with the mysql client, run `SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G`
- Notice everything looks normal (Waiting for master to send event, seconds behind master = 0, etc)
- Try and stop the replication with `STOP SLAVE`
- `STOP SLAVE` hangs
- Impossible to connect to the server with a client
- Execute `SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G` on another already connected client, and it hangs too.

After that, I saw the MySQL process using CPU, and I saw a lot of disk writes with iotop, so I let it do its stuff for a while.

After 15 minutes I killed -9 the MySQL process because I got frustrated. I then restart MySQL, and I can connect and run queries, good.

I execute `SHOW SLAVE STATUS \G` which now works, and it looks normal: seconds behind master = 0, waiting for events. Then I go on the master and execute `CREATE DATABASE foobar` to see if the replication works, and it doesn't.

Again, at that point I see a lot of disk writes so I assume the replication is catching up.
Two hours later, I finally decide to check `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and all I see being executed is a `OPTIMIZE TABLE table1 ...` and then I remember that I had that exact same problem last time.

I kill the process with that query, then I reexecute `SHOW PROCESSLIST` and sure enough it's catching up with the master. `SHOW SLAVE STAUTS \G` reported 15k seconds behind master, which was coherent.

Anyway, after that wall of text, my questions:

- why does a OPTIMIZE query block the replication catching up ?
- can I prevent those OPTIMIZE queries ? I didn't put any cron to do that, and as far as I can see, nothing in /etc/cron.{d,daily,hourly,weekly} does this.

Thanks.

Comment: As a side note, in MariaDB as well as MySQL, if you `STOP SLAVE` during a long-running operation, `STOP SLAVE` will block and subsequent `SHOW SLAVE STATUS` will also block.  That behavior is confusing but normal -- in the interest of data integrity, `STOP SLAVE` does not stop the slave until the current replication event group has finished executing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your First Question

> why does a OPTIMIZE query block the replication catching up ?

The SQL thread in MySQL Replication processes SQL commands from the Relay Logs as a FIFO queue (i.e. first-come, first-server basis). Once the SQL thread see a command, it processes it to completion. Meanwhile, the Seconds_Behind_Master just keeps creeping up.

While the SQL thread on the Slave is running `OPTIMIZE TABLE`, once you run `STOP SLAVE;` it SQL thread has complete the running `OPTIMIZE TABLE` before the SQL thread can terminate. That's why `STOP SLAVE;` hangs. To verify this, open another mysql session and run `SHOW PROCESSLIST;`, You should see a line that has `OPTIMIZE TABLE` with the status `Killing slave...`.

Your Second Question

> can I prevent those OPTIMIZE queries ? I didn't put any cron to do that, and as far as I can see, nothing in /etc/cron.{d,daily,hourly,weekly} does this.

Someone or something is running the `OPTIMIZE TABLE`. You have to hunt it down in all your jobs or PHP apps. Use the [*mysqlbinlog*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlbinlog.html) utility to dumps all the binary logs into a text file. Then, grep the text file for `OPTIMIZE TABLE` or `optimize table`. The timestamp of when it was submitted into the binlogs will be a few lines about the command.

When you do find that `OPTIMIZE TABLE` command in your jobs or PHP code, simply run this:

```
SET SQL_LOG_BIN=0; OPTIMIZE TABLE tblname; SET SQL_LOG_BIN=1;
```

This will not register the `OPTIMIZE TABLE` in the binlogs, thus preventing a Slave from replicating it.

As was just pointed out in the comments below, You can also replace

```
OPTIMIZE TABLE tblname;
```

with one of the following:

```
OPTIMIZE NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLE tblname;
OPTIMIZE LOCAL TABLE tblname;
```

to restrict the [**OPTIMIZE TABLE**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimize-table.html) command from landing in the binlogs and thus prevent replication of it.

Comment: `OPTIMIZE LOCAL TABLE tblname` and `OPTIMIZE NO_WRITE_TO_BINLOG TABLE tblname` are equivalent commands that accomplish the same thing -- optimizing the table on the server where the command is issued without writing the statement to the binary log -- without the need to manually set `SQL_LOG_BIN` off and on again.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Thanks, it's been awhile since seeing that syntax. Taken for granted and overlooked too long. Thanks again.

Comment: @RolandoMySQLDBA Thank you, the first part makes sense. For some reason I did not consider an OPTIMIZE query like a regular query. As for the second question, there was in fact someone who launched an OPTIMIZE, but killed it after. I guess it got replicated anyway.